# Is there a way to send the same set of ids to two different action such as new and show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have search controller that searches for sensors. If a user searches for the specific attributes, they get a list of sensor that matches the searched attributes and the amount of searched sensors are stored in a variable called @sensors.

Search Controller Model

```
class Search < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true

    def sensors
        @sensors ||= find_sensors
    end

    def find_sensors
        sensors = Sensor.where(rcomplete: true, lcomplete: true).order(:name)
        # search sensor info
        sensors = sensors.where("lower(name) like lower(?)", "%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?
        sensors = sensors.where("concentrations.value >= ?","#{conc_min}")
        sensors = sensors.where("concentrations.value <= ?","#{conc_max}")

        # search publication info
        sensors = sensors.joins(:publication).where("lower(publications.title) LIKE lower(?)","%#{publication}%") if publication.present?
        if year_min.present?
            sensors = sensors.joins(:publication).where("publications.year >= ?","#{year_min}")
        end
        if year_max.present?
            sensors = sensors.joins(:publication).where("publications.year <= ?","#{year_max}")
        end
        sensors = sensors.joins(:publication).where("lower(publications.author) LIKE lower(?)","%#{author}%") if author.present?
        sensors = sensors.joins(:publication).where("lower(publications.cauthor) LIKE lower(?)","%#{co_author}%") if co_author.present?
        sensors = sensors.joins(:publication).where("lower(publications.institution) LIKE lower(?)","%#{institution}%") if institution.present?
        sensors = sensors.joins(:publication).where("lower(publications.journal) LIKE lower(?)","%#{journal}%") if journal.present?
        sensors = sensors.joins(:publication).where("lower(publications.link) LIKE lower(?)","%#{doi_link}%") if doi_link.present?

        sensors.uniq
    end
end
```

Then the @sensors found goes to the search controller show action.

Search Controller

```
 class SearchesController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action  :authenticate_user!, :only => [:new,:create, :show]
        def show        
           @sensors = @search.sensors


        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
        end
    end
```

In the search show view page, the searched results are shown in a table. Then there is a link to chart called `analyze result` and if clicked it goes to a new page with the sensors_ids.

```
    <%= link_to "Analyze Results", charts_path(sensors_ids: @sensors.map(&:id)) %>
```

In the Chart index page, the sensors ids are carried like this in the controller, which allows the view pages to use the sensors ids

Chart Controller

```
class ChartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_chart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @charts = Chart.all
    @sensors = Sensor.where(id: params[:sensors_ids])
    @sensors.map(&:id)
  end
```

In Chart Index page, the above one is the correct version, but this is not what I want. On the bottom one, it does not work and I know it does not make sense but I want to use that idea.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <%= link_to 'Function Chart', new_function_chart_path(sensors_ids: @sensors.map(&:id)) %>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

Incorrect version.

```
<%= link_to 'Function Chart', new_function_chart_path(sensors_ids: @sensors.map(&:id)), function_chart_path(sensors_ids: @sensors.map(&:id)) %>
```

I would like to use the concentration of the sensor to graph a plot, however the problem is that I need the data from the sensors to go to the function show page and not the function new page. However, I cannot send ids to two different action, so is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

how about redirecting the action?
using [redirect_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to),

in the view:

```
<%= link_to 'Function Chart', function_chart_path(sensors_ids: @sensors.map(&:id), is_redirect: true) %>
```

then in controller:

```
def index
  @charts = Chart.all
  @sensors = Sensor.where(id: params[:sensors_ids])
  @sensors.map(&:id)
  return redirect_to action: :show, sensors_ids: params[:sensors_ids] if params[:is_redirect]
end
```

※code is not tested